# F# SqlCommand dynamically write to SQL table

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, f#, sqlcommand

So I'm trying to Get data from one table (table1) then write selected data to a second table (table2). I'm able to get the data from table1 and select the data I want. I'm having trouble writing it to table2.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
let insertData(data: string []List) =

    let tableName = data.Item(0).GetValue(0).ToString() //Gets the table Name
    let columnTypes = GetDevTableColumnsTypes tableName

    let mutable tableDataTemp = List.empty
    for i = 0 to data.Length-1 do
        let mutable rowDataTemp = List.empty

        for j = 0 to data.Item(i).Length-1 do
            if data.Item(i).GetValue(j).Equals(tableName) then //if statement removes table name from string array.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("tableName removed from data")
            else
                let cellData = data.Item(i).GetValue(j)

                rowDataTemp <- cellData :: rowDataTemp

        let rowData = rowDataTemp |> List.toArray |> Array.rev
        tableDataTemp <- rowData :: tableDataTemp

    let tableData = tableDataTemp |> List.toArray |> Array.rev //Probably unneeded

    let cn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Azure.SQL.CCSettingDev)
    cn.Open()
    let sQL = "INSERT INTO [" + tableName + "] VALUES(@param1)"
    let db = new SqlCommand(sQL, cn)
    db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", tableData)
    db.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When I run the code I get this argument exception pointed at the executeNonQuery:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Object[] to a known managed provider native type.

Now at the moment I'm only working with 2 tables but soon the program is going to be working with multiple tables with different column names so I need this to work regardless of the table it's writing to. table1 and table2 have the same columns. tables 3 and 4 have the same columns as each other but they have different columns to tables 1 and 2.

chosenData is an object array that contains other object arrays.

If you think there's a better way of adding the data instead of adding an array, please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I strongly advise that you reconsider this method. It's plain-old mutable code that performs data entry in an ugly way. This code would be bad in C#. F# doesn't offer anything. Why use `GetValue` to get at an array item? Why use `ToString()` when the array is *already* a string array? Why pass both the table name *and* the field values in the same array? What is all this code doing??

Comment: Please explain what your actual business problem is, not how you tried to solve it. It looks like you want to MERGE a list of records into a table? Or insert only new records? Write an `INSERT ... WHERE` statement that joins with the table parameter and only inserts new records. Pass the table parameter as a DataTable.

Comment: if your referring to the first line data.GetValue(0).ToString(). When I remove the tostring, tableName becomes an obj and thus incompatible. What it's passed (data) is the table name plus a number reference to a point in an array. So say the number passed is a 2. That means I want the 3rd value in the existInTable1. I have an obj array where I want to add the values in the array to my second table. I should've mentioned the whole program is a web api

Comment: Don't do that. use *specific* parameters. If the first value is a table name, replace it with a `tableName` parameter. In any case, you haven't explained what the *actual* problem is.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to add an array of arrays to an SQL table. The program throws the error I specified earlier. I don't know why. This is the first time I've done anything like this. Sorry if I'm being a pain.

Comment: That's because the entire program is wrong, including the SQL statement and the parameters. You *can't* pass an array to a SQL command. If you want to pass a TVP, you should treat it as a table, ie `VALUES(@whatever)` is wrong, unless you pass a single value. You *can't* avoid specifying the columns otherwise the data will end in the wrong place. Just because you know that `data.[2]` is `John` and `data.[3]` is `Doe`, it doesn't mean that the database columns are in the same order

Comment: Try to write a correct SQL statement first. Then try to execute that statement correctly. *Then* try to pass a table-valued parameter. Or use SqlBulkCopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring)
    cn.Open()

```
for i=0 to tableData.Length-1 do
    let mutable columnsTemp = ""
    let mutable valuesTemp = ""
    for j = 0 to tableData.Item(i).Length-2 do
        columnsTemp <- columnsTemp + columnNames.GetValue(j).ToString() + ","
        valuesTemp <- valuesTemp + "'" + tableData.Item(i).GetValue(j).ToString() + "',"


    let columns = columnsTemp.Remove(columnsTemp.Length-1,1)
    let values = valuesTemp.Remove(valuesTemp.Length-1,1)
    let sQL = "INSERT INTO [" + tableName + "] (" + columns + ") VALUES (" + values + ")"
    let db = new SqlCommand(sQL, cn)
    db.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [table-valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx). I think here the easiest way would be to convert your `chosenData` to an array of `SqlDataRecord` and then do

```
let sQL = "INSERT INTO [" + tableName + "] SELECT * FROM @param1"
```

Comment: That's not enough. The OP is passing a list instead of a DataTable

Comment: I don't understand how this works. Would I have to create a type that contains the names and types of each column, because if so I can't do that. The program can't have any hard coded table values like that, because if the tables in the database change, I'll have to change the code, which is something I don't want. I just want it to work no matter what table it's writing too.

Comment: @JacksonSentzke you can't do that. Which object will end up in which column? Anyway, the easiest way to insert data is to use SqlBulkCopy, pass it a DataTable (which is *not* hard-coded) and ensure the datatable columns match the table column names. Insert the data into a temporary table then merge them into the final table.